# Laravel-Maintenance Mode Page Not Showing

Tags: laravel-5.4

Please see image.

[The command **php artisan down** is working but when i access thru the browser, the maintenance page not showing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM5t7.png)

I am using laravel 5.4.

Please Help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you didnt run `artisan` command to make project run on `127.0.0.1` So you need to run below command after `php artisan down`

```
php artisan serve
```

to check on host `127.0.0.1:8000`

without running this command you can check by running below link in browser

```
localhost/laravel/laravel/public
```

You can also change your port number from `8000` to `8080` or of your choice

```
php artisan serve --port=8080
```

So after running this command your project will be hosted on virtual host `127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: Id like to but my reputation score is not yet enough to vote comments.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks :)

Comment: Whats the difference between "127.0.0.1:8000" and "localhost/laravel/laravel/public" ?

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8000` is generated host for project when we run `php artisan serve` and `localhost/laravel/laravel/public` is public link when we want to use without running command `php artisan serve`

Comment: @ktaro see my updated answer for changing port number

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks @Leena :).